# displaying custom UIimageview within prototype cell in UItableview embedded in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have been following this tutorial: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customize-tableviewcells-with-storyboards To try and create a prototype cell and display a custom image in a UIImageView i place in the table view (as below)

[image: layout of UIView]

I've created my custom class:

```
#import "menuviewcontroller.h"
#import "Menu.h"
#import "MenuCustomCell.h"

@implementation menuviewcontroller
@synthesize menuArray;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];

    self.menuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:4];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Dob in a Hoon menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Report a Hazard menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Old Logo menu.png"]];
    [menuArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Council Website menu.png"]];
}


-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.menuArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
    MenuCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.menuImage.image = menuArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


@end
```

and created a custom cell .m & .h file. (.m is blank)

.h

```
@interface MenuCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *menuImage;

@end
```

But i cannot specify a custom class in the properties of the tableview:

[image]

So the issues i have are:

The images are not being loaded into the tableview
and i am getting a SIGBRAT when i try to build.

Can anybody see where i am going wrong?

Comment: post the SIGABRT error

Comment: `[RoadSafetyAppViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c956c50'
*** First throw call stack:
`

Comment: Seems there is some problem with your delegate setup for the TableView in use. the delegate method in question should have been called on `menuviewcontroller` as seen from your code above, but the method call `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]:` is going to `RoadSafetyAppViewController`. check that. Check the setting in XIB for the delegate of the TableView in use as well.

Comment: this is the problem - i can't change the class on the embedded tableview - it keeps defaulting back to UITableView

Comment: No Problem with that. the problem seems to be with the delegate for the tableview. check the XIB properly and remove all delegate relations for the TableView. The delegate of your tableView should be `MenuViewController` not `RoadSafetyAppViewController`

Comment: Thanks - I'm no longer receiving the SIB+GBRAT error - now my images aren't being displayed.

Comment: for that u need to check your `cellforrow` and `menuArray`. put a breakpoint in `cellforrow` and see if it is getting called ?

Comment: i don't have a cellforrow anywhere in my code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60047/discussion-between-croyneaus4u-and-scb998).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At 1st: 
in viewDidLoad MenuArray:

```
self.menuArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Your objects 1", @"2",@"...", nil];
```

Then in "cellForRowAtIndexPath:"
// in configuration of cell

```
UIImage *menuArrays = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.menuArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
cell.menuArray.image = menuArrays;
```